# Building NFC APDU frames in Android

Tags: java, android, nfc, apdu, hce

I need to send a short string(less than 50 characters) from a Linux machine to an app running on an Android Phone. Due to the difficulty of acquiring an NFC device+software capable of HCE in Linux, and the fact that NFC P2P in Android seems to only be usable through Android Beam, I've elected to do the HCE in Android. My plan is to either write the string directly, or as part of a command APDU to a HostApduService I've written running on the Android phone.

I've had a look at the Android documentation and related classes, but I can't find any code samples for building APDU frames to send back to the Linux reader. Can anyone recommend native Android or 3rd party libraries for creating these frames? Also, can anyone recommend good introductory references for building APDU frames?

Comment: Did you read [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/hce.html)? The callback which is called and should build a response APDU is [HostApduService.processCommandApdu()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/cardemulation/HostApduService.html)

Comment: Yeah I have read that, `processCommandApdu()` returns a byte[] array. My question is how best to build that. Making it by hand seems error-prone and less readable than using a library to build the array.

Comment: It depends on your 'payload' format. You might like [the ByteBuffer class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html). For converting strings `String.getBytes(charset)` might be used (using the same charset on both sides). Do not forget to append the status word to the end of response APDU (probably `0x9000` in your case)